# Reuse Vim terminal buffer

Tags: bash, vim, terminal

When working on Bash scripts in Vim 8, I often execute the current buffer in a split terminal with

```
:terminal %
```

but the second time I run this command, a new buffer is opened rather than reusing the previous one, resulting in multiple open terminals unless I explicitly close the first one.

Is there a way to have Vim always reuse the same buffer for the `:terminal` command? A one-liner that I can drop into my .vimrc is preferred.

Comment: I think it might be easier to just open a default terminal and call your command from there. To call it again, up-arrow key + enter, or k + enter if you have something similar to Bash vi-style input in your shell.

Comment: Also, a simple `:!%:p` can do the job of executing your script in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

`:help :terminal` says:

> Open a new terminal window.

and there's AFAIK no way to tell `:terminal` to reuse an existing window.

You *might* be able to build your own alternative to `:terminal` with `:help term_start()` and the `term_opencmd` option, though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably try experimenting with `term_start()` if no one posts a solution here. I was hoping to get an answer where someone had already worked it out (or found an alternative approach).

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to go a bit further, you could actually use a combination of `tmux` with `send-keys`, `vim` and the file path rather than the buffer itself.

- First you create a tmux session that's preferably running in the same directory as the script will be run:

`tmux new-session -s DEBUGSESSION`

- Then you edit your file called, say, `my_script.sh` which already needs to have the executable flag.

`vim my_script.sh`

- Then from inside vim, you send to the tmux session the keys to run the file:

:!tmux send-keys -t DEBUGSESSION "%:p<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>"

Yes, you could probably also send the buffer instead of the file but if you have a large file I don't know about the performance.

And yes, this limits you to the whole file (as opposed to the buffer, where you can select a number of lines).

But I still think it could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Building on my [earlier answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/38386/43301), the following commands try to reuse the same terminal every time. They open a new window if the old one does not exist, and they fail if a command is still running in the old window. The window retains its geometry from command to command:

```
command! -nargs=1 RunInTerminal silent call s:RunInTerminal(<q-args>)
command! -nargs=? MakeInTerminal silent call s:MakeInTerminal(<q-args>)

function s:RunInTerminal(cmd)
  let l:options = {'term_name': '!' .. a:cmd}
  const l:orig_winid = win_getid()
  if win_gotoid(s:term_winid) == 1
    let l:options['curwin'] = 1
  endif
  call term_start([&g:shell, &g:shellcmdflag, a:cmd], l:options)
  let s:term_winid = win_getid()
  call win_gotoid(l:orig_winid)
endfunction

if !exists('s:term_winid')
  let s:term_winid = 0
endif

function s:MakeInTerminal(args)
  const l:cmd = expandcmd(&makeprg) .. (a:args == '' ? '' : ' ' .. a:args)
  call s:RunInTerminal(l:cmd)
endfunction
```